# Action filter for each method in Laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am building quite an extensive app for a client and I will have to produce some kind of a group permission control. I decided to go with Cartalyst and their **Sentry** package. 
So far so good!

Now the problem I am having is, what is the best way of detecting a user group permission, since there are more than just one, so I can't just use one filter and be done with it.

For example, I would do something like this:

For pages that need admin-level access

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'is_admin'), function()
{
       Route::get('admin', array('as'=>'admin', 'uses'=>'admin@index'));
       // Other methods that require admin-level access
});
```

For pages that need moretaor-level access and so on..

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'is_moderator'), function()

    {
           Route::get('orodja/plosca', array('as'=>'moderator', 'uses'=>'moderator@index'));
           // Other methods that require moderator-level access
    });
```

The problem I'm having with this approach is, that I would need to define a new route for every controller action and this really does not look like best practice to me.

Next I thought about registering all controllers with `Controller::detect()` and make them REST-full but I here the problem is, that I can apply filter only to the constructor method of a controller and not to a single action. What if I have method with different access-level in one controller..?

**So my question is:** What is the best way of getting around this problem and is there any way to apply a action filter to a single controller method, rather than to a controller constructor.

Thanks and sorry for my english!

Comment: I would recommend you to use the approach suggested by Adrenaxus, don't use `Controller::detect` at all. Even tho it looks weird at first, defining each route or even each controller gives you more freedom, is less buggy and more performant. Btw, `Controller::detected` was completely removed from L4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can attach a filter to all requests that start with a given URI (see the [official doc on filters](http://three.laravel.com/docs/routing#filters))

```
Route::filter('pattern: admin/*', 'auth');
```

Or you can attach a filter only to some actions within your controller:

```
$this->filter('before', 'auth')->only(array('index', 'list'));
```

On a side note, you don't have to create a route for every controller action you have. If you register your controller with `Route::controller('admin::home');` it will fire automatically.

Another option would be that you define only one `auth` filter for all roles, then check for the different roles *within* the filter.